# How do I efficiently check roles in PHP Sessions?

Tags: php, session

The project I'm working on right now has multiple site sections that require different levels of access. I have roles set up for regular users, admins, and a superuser. Right now I'm verifying role with this:

```
<?php   
session_start();
$reqrole = "user";
$admin = "admin";
$superuser = "superuser";

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
       {
           header("Location:login.html");  
       }
       if(!isset($_SESSION['role']))
       {
           header("Location:login.html");  
       }
       if ($_SESSION['role'] != $reqrole and $_SESSION['role'] != $superuser and $_SESSION['role'] != $admin)
       {
           header("Location:login.html");  
       }
?>
```

So every time I want to change what role is allowed to access a page or add a new one I have to change the if statement which doesn't seem like the best way to do it. Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: Look at some PHP frameworks implementations of ACLs perhaps?

Comment: "Efficiently" is off topic at SO. You should go to code review with this question. SO is for none working code

Comment: maybe save the roles in an array? then you'd only have to change the array and in the if you can user `in_array()`